# How to land to openAM/idm/EndUser

Tags: openam

I am new to openAM, I have sso url, username and password. My question is how can I land to openAM/idm/EndUser page from my .net application without going to openAM log in page? what kind of service or API should I use for that. Is there a sample demo?

Answer (score 0):

not at all

EndUser page is part of OpenAM console, which is 'protected' by OpenAM itself. Without an OpenAM SSO tracking cookie you can not access it.

What would be the intention to hit the OpenAM console (which should not be made public in Internet space)? Password Change? Identity Management?

Note OpenAM is NOT really an identity management / provisioning 'tool' (and is not a web-frontend to LDAP-based Directory Servers).